# How to deal with changing Flyway migrations?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I am currently investigating [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) as an alternative to [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), but was unable to find an answer to the following question in the documentation:

Assume a migration `X` is found to contain a bug after deployment in production. In retrospect, `X` *should never have been executed as is*, but it's already too late. However, we'd like to replace the migration `X` with a fixed version `X'`, such that databases that are populated from scratch do not suffer from the same bug.

In Liquibase, you would fix the original changeset and use the `<validChecksum>` tag to notify Liquibase that the change was made by purpose. Is there a pendant to `<validChecksum>` in Flyway, or an alternative mechanism that achieves the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is a violation of Flyway's API, the following approach has worked fine for us:

Write a `beforeValidate.sql` that fixes the checksum to match the expected value, so that when Flyway actually validates the checksum, everything seems fine.

An example:

```
-- The script xyz/V03_201808230839__Faulty_migration.sql was modified to fix a critical bug.
-- However, at this point there were already production systems with the old migration file.
-- On these systems, no additional statements need to be executed to reflect the change,
-- BUT we need to repair the Flyway checksum to match the expected value during the 'validate' command.
UPDATE schema_version
SET checksum = -842223670
WHERE (version, checksum) = ('03.201808230839', -861395806);
```

This has the advantage of only targetting one specific migration, unlike Flyway's `repair` command.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how big the mess is you could also

- simply have a follow-up migrations to correct it (typo in new column name, ..)
- if that is not an option, you must manually fix both the migration and the DB and issue Flyway.repair() to realign the checksum http://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair.html

Comment: I know the `repair` command, but that just disables any checksum validation for the given run for all the migrations, right? I am looking for fixing a single changeset instead.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of hiding this bad change if it has already reached production? Is it expensive to replay every time on empty databases (I assume CI runs) ? Make a new db baseline with that migration already included.